# How do I update data in carbon angular chart?

Tags: angular

I have the following code I am using to try and update angular carbon charts line graph.. but the graph seems to not update even though the data is. What am I doing wrong here?

Pressing the button is supposed to add a segment to the array and load in the graph.. I see in the console the data array updating and yet nothing on the graph..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, interval, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { StockService } from './stockService'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stockticker',
  templateUrl: './stockticker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stockticker.component.css']
})

export class StocktickerComponent implements OnInit
{

subscription: Subscription
i = 0
title = "Stocktcker"
    data = []

    options;

    constructor(private stockService: StockService)
    {
        
    }

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.stockService.data$.subscribe(
            (data) => {
              if (data.length)
              {
                this.data = data
              }
              else
              {
              }
            }
          )
          this.options = {
            "title": this.title,
            "curve": "curveMonotoneX",
            "axes": {
              "bottom": {
                "title": "Stocks over time",
                "mapsTo": "key",
                "scaleType": "linear"
              },
              "left": {
                "mapsTo": "value",
                "title": "Value",
                "scaleType": "linear",
                "domain": [
                  0,
                  1.8
                ]
              }
            },
            "height": "300px"
          }
}

    onClick()
    {
        this.i += 1
        this.data.push({
            "group": "groupname",
            "key": this.i,
            "value": this.AMOUNTS[getRandom(this.AMOUNTS.length)]
          })
          this.stockService.setData(this.data)
    }
}

function getRandom(max)
{
    // return (Math.random() * (0 - 2) + 2).toFixed(4)
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}
```

HTML Portion:

```
<ibm-line-chart [data]="data" [options]="options"></ibm-line-chart>
<button nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="onClick()">Turn</button>
```

Service portion:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable
(
    {
        providedIn: 'root'
    }
)
export class StockService
{

    data$: Observable<any>
    private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({})

    constructor()
    {
        this.data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable()
    }

    setData(newData)
    {
        this.dataSubject.next(newData)
        console.log(newData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just pushing in the array but this needs to be reminded to angular change detection that there is an update already made in `data`

try below code instead,

```
onClick()
{
    this.i += 1
    this.data.push({
        "group": "groupname",
        "key": this.i,
        "value": this.AMOUNTS[getRandom(this.AMOUNTS.length)]
      })
      this.data = [...this.data];
      this.stockService.setData(this.data)
}
```

Comment: That worked.. and didnt need to muck with any of that observable stuff.. ty for the quick and easy solution.. I wish this was pointed out in the docs. Or did I miss something?!

Comment: this is how angular works :) you can upvote if that was helpful !

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do something similar for dict?

Comment: I am basically trying to update the options of the graph along with the data. Try to make like a sliding window left to right.

Comment: well the idea is whenever you make any changes in the graph ensure you change the object reference and don't mutate the object rather change the object

Comment: I ended up using this.options = object.assign(this.options) this seems to be the way to modify the refence.

Comment: Destructuring or any object is the same in your context, es6 has destructuring. If no then you could also use Object.assign the idea will still remain same.

`a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] //Console output

b = Object.assign(a);
(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]//Console output

c= [...a]
(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]//Console output`

Comment: I can use the ... operator for lists, seems to fail with dict. so I used assign for those.